# Effects of sound multiplication

Tags: audio, soundeffect

What are the effects of multiplication of two different sound? An neither of them are constant, like two different songs, or one track of instrumental and one of vocals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple Google search came up with this:

http://crca.ucsd.edu/~msp/techniques/v0.11/book-html/node77.html

Did you search for it at all?

But basically what happens is you end up creating an envelope where the second acts as a "coefficient" of sorts.

You also end up with a reduction of sound levels (since a decimal times a decimal is less both of them), so you'll need to amplify the signal a bit to retain volume.

The page I linked gives a lot more explanation and has a lot of the algebra needed to write up a code to implement it. Look there if you have any more questions.